# Spacetime with a point defect

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, cosmic-string, topological-defects

What is the metric for a spacetime with a point defect? Spacetime metric with line defects are well-known, they are basically Cosmic strings. Is anyone aware of an example for spacetime with point defects?

Comment: [Magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) are one type of point defect.

Comment: I don't know about monopoles generally but it can be shown that the action of a point particles (or $0$-brane) is the Schwarzschild metric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that what OP is looking for is the spacetime of *global monopole*, a solution of GR with a deficit of solid angle:
$$
 ds^2=-dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{\alpha ^2}+r^2d\theta ^2+r^2\sin ^2\theta d\varphi ^2,\tag{*}
$$
where $\alpha<1$. Metric of this type arises as a solution of Einstein field equation with the matter in the form of triplet of scalar fields with a “mexican hat”–type potential with *global* $SO(3)$ symmetry. This global symmetry is broken by via a “hedgehog”-like ansats. Near the origin the metric actually has “microstructure”, so rather than conical singularity of $(*)$ the curvature remains bounded, plus there is also a small negative mass term.

Reference:

- Barriola, M., & Vilenkin, A. (1989). *Gravitational field of a global monopole*. Physical Review Letters, 63(4), 341, [doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.341](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.341).